# Finding match for div tag in Java + Android

Tags: java, android, rss

Please I need to get any occurrence of a div tag in a String value in Java.
The location of this div tag in the String is not known ahead.
Can anyone please help with any hint or link that an be helpful regarding this?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a sample String?

Comment: do you want to remove all div tags?

Comment: String Str = "abc<div>def";
if(str.contains("<div>")||str.contains("<DIV>")){
// there is <div> tag in your string. do your code.
}

Comment: If there is a div tag in the string, then I need to select the div tag to the end of the div tag and remove it out of the string for further parsing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String xml = "<div><![CDATA[<p>hellowrold</p>]]></div>";
        String xpath = "/div/text()";
        XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        String childHtml = xPath.evaluate(xpath, new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));

        System.out.println(childHtml);

        xpath = "/p";
        String result = xPath.evaluate(xpath, new InputSource(new StringReader(childHtml)));

        System.out.println(result);

    }

}
```

Xpath is used to traverse XML. You can do much more with XPath. In your case the problem is with CDATA tags that are hiding the elements which you want to extract. The above should help you get away with that. What has been done above ? first extract the CDATA tags as separate xml and then apply xpath on it.

Comment: Need to get Images src attributes' value <p><a href="http://thenet.ng/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Apaye.png"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-175999" alt="Apaye" src="http://thenet.ng/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Apaye.png" width="600" height="305" /></a></p>

Comment: I need to extract the string of div tag from the begiining of the tag to the end of the div tag.